# Approximability of the edge-disjoint shortest paths problem

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, shortest-path, approximation

In the *edge-disjoint paths problem* (EDP), we are given a (possibly directed) graph $G=(V,E)$, and a set of distinct source-sink pairs $\{ (s_i,t_i) \mid 1 \leq i \leq k \}$, and we want to maximize the number of pairs that can be simultaneously connected in an edge-disjoint manner. When we add the constraint that the paths need to be *shortest paths*, we get the *edge-disjoint shortest paths* (EDSP) problem.

According to [1], the EDSP problem is hard for a graph with unit edge lengths, even when the graph is planar. Furthermore, it claims this is so for both directed and undirected graphs.

> What is known about the approximability of the EDSP problem?

I'm especially interested in results for undirected graphs. In [2], the authors seem to only consider variants of the EDP problem, but not the EDSP problem. Further following the references, it seems like the EDP problem has been studied extensively.

---

[1] [Eilam-Tzoreff, Tali. "The disjoint shortest paths problem." Discrete applied mathematics 85.2 (1998): 113-138.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X97001212)

[2] [Guruswami, Venkatesan, et al. "Near-optimal hardness results and approximation algorithms for edge-disjoint paths and related problems." Journal of Computer and System Sciences 67.3 (2003): 473-496.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000003000667)

Answer (score 1):

**Below, we will assume there is exactly one shortest path between every pair of vertices.** The following will also work for the case where $O(\log n)$ pairs of vertices have $O(1)$ shortest paths between them.

For each pair $\{s_i , t_i\}$ let the shortest path be $P_i$, $\forall i \in \{0,1\ldots k\}$. The shortest path can be found in polynomial time. Let us number the edges $e_1, e_2, \ldots e_q$. Let the maximum number of pairs $\{s_i , t_i\}$ for which there exist disjoint-shortest paths be $\text{OPT}$.

Now, we reduce this problem to an optimization problem.

Define a matrix $A_{k\times q}$ such that $A_{ij} = 1 \text{ if } e_j \in P_i$.

$$
\text{OPT} = \max \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \quad 
\\
\text{s.t } Ax \leq \mathbf{1}_{n\times 1} \\ 
x \in \{0,1\}
$$

Let the optimal fractional solution for the above problem be $\text{OPT}_{\text{LP}}$ and $\text{OPT}_{\text{LP}} \geq \text{OPT}$. The above LP has an integrality gap of $O(\log k)$. Therefore, $O(\log k) \cdot \text{OPT}_{\text{IP}} \geq \text{OPT}_{\text{LP}}$. Thus $ O(\log k) \cdot \text{OPT}_{\text{IP}} \geq \text{OPT}$. Hence we obtain a $O(\log k)$ approximation algorithm.

The proof for the integrality gap result can be found in **Vazirani's "Approximation Algorithms", chapter 20. Multicut in General Graphs.**